# Setting label value for varied symbology by attribute using size as variation

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, arcade

In using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.1, I wanted to have symbology that represented two attributes at one time. This is possible using a variety of symbology setups, specifically, I did the following:

Created a Primary Symbology using Unique Values as shown below:
[image]

Then I changed the Vary symbology by attribute tab and used a custom expression to set the unique values to be different sizes based on my expression as shown below:

[image]

My symbology of the custom expression has resulted in the below:

[image]

How can I customize the label values from being 6, 14, 22, & 30?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would try to do this is by using [Attribute-driven symbology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/attribute-driven-symbology.htm) to [Reflect feature attribution in symbols](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/attribute-driven-symbology.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_B7D3C5EBEB814318A6A5A59853D5A9B7) (with my bolding):

> You can customize symbols to reflect different aspects of the data
>   they draw. There are a variety of ways to do this:
>
> ...
>
> - Control the **size**, rotation, color, or transparency, in addition to their primary symbology.

although it sounds like this may already be what you are doing.  If so, including more details of your precise workflow, and the issue you have with those size symbols may enable a potential answerer to apply fresh eyes to the options at each step.